# scipy.stats.chi2 returns Nan probability

Tags: python, scipy, probability, chi-squared

I need to calculate the Chi^2 probability of a dataset that is expected to follow a Poisson distribution. I have my observed frequencies and theoretical frequencies. My degrees of freedom is 7.

```
 realFreq = [ 2.  3.  9.  8.  6.  2.  2.  1.]

 expectedFreq = [ 1.69352235  5.0292482   7.46767156  7.39224054  
 5.48817858 3.25964546 1.61335987  0.6844557 ]

 dof = 7

 chi_statistic, p_value = scipy.stats.chisquare(realFreq,expectedFreq,dof)
```

This, unfortunately, returns a correct value of Chi^2 but no associated probability.

```
  statistic=2.0112702570397993, pvalue=nan
```

It should return me a value of pvalue=0.959218.

If I leave the dof argument it returns some value.

Up to 6 degrees of freedom it returns a p value.

Where am I going wrong? Am I lagging understanding of the matter or is it some usage of the `scipy.stats.chisquare` function?

Thanks in advance,

Gordon

Comment: You're not the first person to get tripped up by the meaning of the `ddof` argument.

Answer (score 1):

My mistake. The documentation of `scipy.stats.chisquare(f_obs = , f_exp= , ddof = )`

Where `ddof` stands for delta degrees of freedom. As the function automatically assumes the degrees of freedom to be N-1.